How to best implement many-to-many in SQLAlchemy?
I have a table for users, series, and movies, and I need to create a 'Watchlist' table that includes the movies and series a user plans to watch in the future. How is this best implemented? I understand how to link just two tables, but I struggle when it comes to three.
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "movies"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

class Series(Base):
    __tablename__ = "series"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

And in general, is a many-to-many relationship appropriate for this scenario?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

There isn't an exact way.  Usually you just have to try something out and then refactor as necessary.  Probably start by making a table for the watchlist items.
class WatchlistItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'watchlist_items'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    # Could be "movie" or "series".
    media_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    movie_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("movies.id"), nullable=True)
    series_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("series.id"), nullable=True)
    series: Mapped[Series] = relationship("Series")
    movie: Mapped[Movie] = relationship("Movie")
    sortby: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(default=0)

#... get them from the db
for item in watchlist_items:
    if item.media_type == 'movie':
        # do something with item.movie
        pass
    elif item.media_type == 'series':
        # do something with item.series
        pass


I usually just do something like above but you can also use inheritance seen here:
mapping-class-inheritance-hierarchies
It might be easier once you start thinking about linking in the user and quickly grabbing their items to add a separate class for the watchlist itself such as:
class Watchlist(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'watchlists'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id", nullable=False)

Finally, another example of a different way would be to consolidate both Movie and Series into a class called Watchable.  This depends on if there are mostly shared columns between Movie and Series.  So like this(some columns can be NULL depending on the kind):
class WatchlistItem(Base):
    #... boiler plate stuff
    watchable: Mapped["Watchable"] = relationship("Watchable")

class Watchable(Base):
    #... boiler plate stuff
    # movie, series, short, etc.
    kind: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    #...

